# xpath to get Node containing text

Tags: xml, xpath

I tried to search for nodes containing text 'Yahoo' under '/doc/story/content', it returns 'content' node, but I need exact text node that contains 'Yahoo' or it's parent

```
<doc>
    <story>
        <content id="201009281450332423">
            <ul>MSW NYNES NYPG1 DILMA</ul>
            <p> <k> Yahoo, made </k> it nice </p>
            <p>
               <author>-v-</author>
            </p>
        </content>
    </story>
</doc>
```

Xpath: `"/doc/story/content[contains(., 'Yahoo')]"`

Answer (score 60):

Since you need all textNodes only which contain the text ***Yahoo***, use the following XPath.

```
//text()[contains(., 'Yahoo')]
```

This should return you all the textNodes only which contains ***Yahoo*** (case-sensitive) in it.

Comment: What it the difference between this answer and @Jon's?

Comment: Case insensitive: //text()[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÜÉÈÊÀÁÂÒÓÔÙÚÛÇÅÏÕÑŒ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöüéèêàáâòóôùúûçåïõñœ'),'yahoo')]

Answer (score 42):

Your XML is malformed. `</content></doc></story>` should be `</content></story></doc>`.

Apart from that, the XPath you would want is

```
/doc/story/content//*[contains(., 'Yahoo')]
```

(select any descendant of `<content>` which contains the text "Yahoo" -- this will select the `<p>`)

Comment: This works great if it's one level down, How to make it work for multi-nested tags?

Comment: @Vjy: I 'm not sure what you mean. Can you give an example?

Comment: Updated the above xml with additional tag <K>, it should select K instead of P tag. this is just example, the text node can be n level deep.

Comment: @Vjy: this does exactly what you asked for.

Comment: text() is a node test not a string. contains() expects strings. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9493870/695671 Your solution may appear to work, but I have a case with text nodes within text nodes in which case it fails.

Comment: @JasonS: That situation did not cross my mind (how did you manage to do it? programmatically?). I have corrected the answer accordingly. Thank you for pointing that out, I feel I learned something new.

Comment: @Jon I did it as in your updated answer. I am getting content from text nodes in odt files using PHP SimpleXMLElement. The odt often has paragraphs with tabs and spaces represented like  `<text:p Hello<text:s/><text:tab/>Jon</text:p>`, in which case searching using `contains(text(),"Jon")` will fail, but `contains(.,"Jon")` will work.