# Get data from <script> tag in HTML using Scrapy

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I've been trying to extract data from script tag in Kbb's HTML using Scrapy(xpath). But my main issue is with identifying the correct div and script tags. I'm new to using xpath and would appreciate any help!

HTML (http://www.kbb.com/nissan/altima/2014/25-s-sedan-4d/?vehicleid=392396&intent=buy-used&mileage=10000&condition=fair&pricetype=retail):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s1.kbb.com/combine/IncentivesPilotJs/949332058"></script>
        <input type="hidden" id="ResaleValueUrl" value="/ymmt/resalevalue/?vehicleid=392396" />
        <input type="hidden" id="Intent" value="buy-used" />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script>
            window.FlashCanvasOptions = {
               swfPath: "/js/canvas/FlashCanvas/UCMarketMeter/"
            };
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s1.kbb.com/combine/YmmtMarketMeterFlashCanvasJs/795892638"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s1.kbb.com/combine/YMMTOverview/1527402533"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s1.kbb.com/combine/YmmtPricingOverviewBuyUsedJs/-1416499456"></script>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                KBB.Vehicle.Pages.PricingOverview.Buyers.setup({
                    //Workaround until we get cross domain working for Flash
                    imageDir: window.FlashCanvasOptions ? "/Content/images" : "http://file.kelleybluebookimages.com/kbb/images/marketmeter",
                    vehicleId: "392396",
                    zipCode: "78701",
                    mileage: "10000",
                    intent: "buy-used",
                    priceType: "retail",
                    condition: "good",
                    options: "392396|53635|78701|100|10|",
                    price: "17074",
                    manufacturer: "Nissan",
                    model: "Altima",
                    year: "2014",
                    style: "2.5 S Sedan 4D",
                    category: "",
                    hasCpo: true,
                    meetsCpoReq: true,
                    showOthersPaid: false,
                    data: {
    "values": {
     "cpo": {
       "priceMin": 17335.0,
        "price": 18275.0,
        "priceMax": 19214.0
    },
    "fpp": {
      "priceMin": 15286.0,
      "price": 17074.0,
      "priceMax": 18861.0
    },
    "privatepartyexcellent": {
      "priceMin": 0.0,
      "price": 16064.0,
      "priceMax": 0.0
    },
    "privatepartyfair": {
      "priceMin": 0.0,
      "price": 14081.0,
      "priceMax": 0.0
    },
    "privatepartygood": {
      "priceMin": 0.0,
      "price": 15454.0,
      "priceMax": 0.0
    },
    "privatepartyverygood": {
      "priceMin": 0.0,
      "price": 15715.0,
      "priceMax": 0.0
    },
    "retail": {
      "priceMin": 0.0,
      "price": 17875.0,
      "priceMax": 0.0
    }
  },
     "timAmount": 0.0,
    "monthlyPayments": {
    "cpo": {
      "vehiclePrice": 18275.0,
      "rate": 2.9,
      "terms": 60.0,
      "taxAndTitle": 6.5,
      "downPay": 0.0,
      "amount": 348.0
    },
    "fpp": {
      "vehiclePrice": 17074.0,
      "rate": 4.9,
      "terms": 60.0,
      "taxAndTitle": 6.5,
      "downPay": 0.0,
      "amount": 342.0
    },
    "privatepartyexcellent": {
      "vehiclePrice": 16064.0,
      "rate": 4.9,
      "terms": 60.0,
      "taxAndTitle": 6.5,
      "downPay": 0.0,
      "amount": 322.0
    },
    "privatepartyfair": {
      "vehiclePrice": 14081.0,
      "rate": 4.9,
      "terms": 60.0,
      "taxAndTitle": 6.5,
      "downPay": 0.0,
      "amount": 282.0
    },
    "privatepartygood": {
      "vehiclePrice": 15454.0,
      "rate": 4.9,
      "terms": 60.0,
      "taxAndTitle": 6.5,
      "downPay": 0.0,
      "amount": 309.0
    },
    "privatepartyverygood": {
      "vehiclePrice": 15715.0,
      "rate": 4.9,
      "terms": 60.0,
      "taxAndTitle": 6.5,
      "downPay": 0.0,
      "amount": 315.0
    },
    "retail": {
      "vehiclePrice": 17875.0,
      "rate": 4.9,
      "terms": 60.0,
      "taxAndTitle": 6.5,
      "downPay": 0.0,
      "amount": 358.0
    }
  },
  "scale": {
    "scaleLow": 14081.0,
    "scaleHigh": 19214.0
  },
  "transactions": {
    "below": 7,
    "between": 17,
    "above": 3
  }
},
                    adPriceRanges: {"AdPriceRange":[{"PriceMin":0,"PriceMax":8499,"AdPRValue":1},{"PriceMin":8500,"PriceMax":18499,"AdPRValue":2},{"PriceMin":18500,"PriceMax":23499,"AdPRValue":3},{"PriceMin":23500,"PriceMax":28499,"AdPRValue":4},{"PriceMin":28500,"PriceMax":33499,"AdPRValue":5},{"PriceMin":33500,"PriceMax":38499,"AdPRValue":6},{"PriceMin":38500,"PriceMax":43499,"AdPRValue":7},{"PriceMin":43500,"PriceMax":48499,"AdPRValue":8},{"PriceMin":48500,"PriceMax":53499,"AdPRValue":9},{"PriceMin":53500,"PriceMax":63499,"AdPRValue":10},{"PriceMin":63500,"PriceMax":73499,"AdPRValue":11},{"PriceMin":73500,"PriceMax":1000000,"AdPRValue":12}]}});
            });
            $('.foot-note').hide();
            $(window).on('popstate', function() {
                KBB.Vehicle.Pages.PricingOverview.Buyers.stateChangeHandler();
            });
        </script>


Scrapy Code:

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import scrapy

from kbb.items import kbbItem

class kbbSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "kbb"
allowed_domains = ["kbb.com"]
start_urls = [
    "http://www.kbb.com/nissan/altima/2014/25-s-sedan-4d/?vehicleid=392396&intent=buy-used&10000&good&pricetype=retail"
]

def parse(self, response):
    sel=Selector(response)
    #sites=sel.xpath('//div')
    items=[]
    #for site in sites:
    item=kbbItem
    item['priceMin']=site.xpath('//div/script').extract[35][915:922]
    return items
```

I finally want to populate `priceMin`, `price`, `priceMax` from `fpp` and price from `retail` field into my items. Currently I'm using indices to get those values but was wondering if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that the desired data is inside the Javascript code. And, your current approach where you rely on line indexes is quite fragile and unreliable.

The idea is to locate the `script` tag containing the desired data, use [regular expressions](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions) to get to the object/dictionary containing prices, load the object into a python dictionary with the help of [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) and get the desired information.

Demo from the [Scrapy Shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html):

```
In [1]: import re
In [2]: import json

In [3]: pattern = re.compile(r"KBB\.Vehicle\.Pages\.PricingOverview\.Buyers\.setup\(.*?data: ({.*?}),\W+adPriceRanges", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
In [4]: data = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'KBB.Vehicle.Pages.PricingOverview.Buyers.setup')]/text()").re(pattern)[0]

In [5]: data = data.replace("//Workaround until we get cross domain working for Flash", "")

In [6]: data_obj = json.loads(data)

In [7]: data_obj['values']['fpp']
Out[7]: {u'price': 15569.0, u'priceMax': 17356.0, u'priceMin': 13781.0}

In [8]: data_obj['values']['retail']
Out[8]: {u'price': 16370.0, u'priceMax': 0.0, u'priceMin': 0.0}
```

Comment: Thanks for your amazing response @alecxe. Could you please also explain how to change the "pattern"(regex mainly) variable to get the data on mileage, condition, make, model etc. which are above the 'data' dict.

Comment: @outlier123 Thanks! How about smth like `response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'KBB.Vehicle.Pages.PricingOverview.Buyers.setup')]/text()").re(r'mileage: "(\d+)",')[0]`?

Comment: awesome!! so we just have to find the right regex i guess. Thanks for your responses @alecxe

Comment: This was a great answer but too complicated for me.  See below if your work is simpler and needs to use xpath to isolate a script with certain property: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041475/using-xpath-to-isolate-inline-javascript