# Get data from script tag with Scrapy Xpath

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I've been trying to extract data from script tag using Scrapy(xpath). My main issue is with identifying the correct div and script tags. I'm new to using xpath and would appreciate any help!

```
<script>
    (function(e, a) {
            var t = {
                "cdn_url": "https://f.vimeocdn.com",
                "view": 1,
                "request": {
                    "files": {
                        "dash": {
                            "separate_av": true,
                            "streams": [{
                                "profile": 164,
                                "quality": "360p",
                                "id": 830872409,
                                "fps": 30
                            }, {
                                "profile": 175,
                                "quality": "1080p",
                                "id": 830872420,
                                "fps": 30
                            }]
                            "default_cdn": "akfire_interconnect_quic"
                        },
                        "progressive": [{
                            "profile": 165,
                            "width": 960,
                            "mime": "video/mp4",
                            "fps": 30,
                            "url": "https://gcs-vimeo.akamaized.net/exp=1512626028~acl=%2A%2F830872419.mp4%2A~hmac=f6990c94f8fe004ec50059b0c1c648441faa41b248a14e881826a4b1233676c3/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/1812/9/234061739/830872419.mp4",
                            "cdn": "akamai_interconnect",
                            "quality": "540p",
                            "id": 830872419,
                            "origin": "gcs",
                            "height": 540
                        }, {
                            "profile": 174,
                            "width": 1280,
                            "mime": "video/mp4",
                            "fps": 30,
                            "url": "https://gcs-vimeo.akamaized.net/exp=1512626028~acl=%2A%2F830872411.mp4%2A~hmac=ad12d7e5de00edb54c2360e23429d4a5de6aa0800ff7f4273f2ecc4495171707/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/1812/9/234061739/830872411.mp4",
                            "cdn": "akamai_interconnect",
                            "quality": "720p",
                            "id": 830872411,
                            "origin": "gcs",
                            "height": 720
                        }, {
                            "profile": 164,
                            "width": 640,
                            "mime": "video/mp4",
                            "fps": 30,
                            "url": "https://gcs-vimeo.akamaized.net/exp=1512626028~acl=%2A%2F830872409.mp4%2A~hmac=26c477008c9a74d4ceca9895c5307ab19c6ef79e7480e833a503f15ea60bdf2b/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/1812/9/234061739/830872409.mp4",
                            "cdn": "akamai_interconnect",
                            "quality": "360p",
                            "id": 830872409,
                            "origin": "gcs",
                            "height": 360
                        }]
                    },
                    .....
</script>
```

I finally want to populate "url" from "progressive" where "width"= 960 into my items.

Comment: you can get all from <script> only as one string and you have to use standard string functions or regex to get what you need.

Comment: value assigned to `var t =` looks like JSON data. If you get it as string then you can convert it into python dictionary using `json` module. And then you can find element in dictionary.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503643/get-data-from-script-tag-in-html-using-scrapy