# How can I access the < script type = "text/x-magento-init" > tag using python scrapy xpath?

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I want to extract the data that is in < script type = "text/x-magento-init" > tag. But I am not able to access it. is there a way to do that?
URL=https://sortiment.lidl.ch/de/papier-tragetasche-fsc-0123997.html
To be precise I need the images of the product that is being displayed on this url. **Both the images.

I want to "full" item.

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you please show us your effort ?

Comment: `response.css('script')[x]` at lease please find the target script first

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get data from <script> tag in HTML using Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503643/get-data-from-script-tag-in-html-using-scrapy)