# XPath //div[contains(text(), 'string')] fails to select divs containing 'string'

Tags: html, xpath

This is the HTML code:

```
<div>  <span></span>  Elangovan  </div>
```

I want to write an XPath for the `div` based on its contained text.  I tried

```
//div[contains(text(),'Elangovan')]
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Replace `text()` with [`string()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string):

```
//div[contains(string(), "Elangovan")]
```

Or, you can check that `span`'s following text sibling contains the text:

```
//div[contains(span/following-sibling::text(), "Elangovan")]
```

Also see:

- [Difference between text() and string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493732/difference-between-text-and-string)

Comment: @alecxe you sir, are my hero! Finally I can select text like <p>Hello <strong>World</strong></p>

Answer (score 20):

Alternatively to alecxe's correct answer (+1), the following slightly simpler and somewhat more idiomatic XPath will work the same way:

```
//div[contains(., "Elangovan")]
```

**The reason that your original XPath with [`text()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests) does not work is** that `text()` will select all text node children of `div`.  However, `contains()` expects a string in its first argument, and when given a node set of text nodes, *it only uses the first one*.  Here, the first text node contains whitespace, not the sought after string, so the test fails.   With the implicit `.` or the explicit [**`string()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string) first argument, all text node descendants are concatenated together before performing the `contains()` test, so the test passes.

Comment: plus one, very detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

To make @kjhughes's already good answer just a little more precise, what you're really asking for is a way to look for substrings in the `div`'s [string-value](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value):

> For every type of node, there is a way of determining a string-value
>   for a node of that type. For some types of node, the string-value is
>   part of the node; for other types of node, the string-value is
>   computed from the string-value of descendant nodes.

Both the context node (`.` or the `div` itself) and the set of nodes returned by `text()` -- or any other argument! -- are first converted to strings when passed to `contains`. It's just that they're converted in different ways, because one refers to a single element and the other refers to a node-set.

A single element's string-value is the concatenation of the string-values of all its text node descendants. A node-set's string-value, on the other hand, is the string-value of the node in the set that is first in document order.

So the real difference is in what you're converting to a string and how that conversion takes place.

Comment: The string-value link and explanation provided by @lwburk are valuable contributions and worth understanding.  +1