# How to find an element by text with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to access click a hashtag on Instagram with Selenium, so I can see all images related to that hashtag.

The problem is, that the hashtag, which you are searching for is not always on the top...
Is there a way to find and click the hashtag I am searching for?

[See the problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzEUm.png)

Would be cool if you could help me :)

```
def likeByHashtag(self,hashtag):
    #click on the magnifying glass
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/section/nav[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/a")))
    element.click()
    #type in searchbar
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/section/nav[1]/div/header/div/h1/div/div/div/div[1]/label/input")))
    element.send_keys("#" +hashtag)
    #click on #
    element = xxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific case, the most efficient solution would be to directly navigate to the endpoint containing your hashtag.
So you'd need to:

`driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/' + hashtag)` in your `likeByHashtag` function.

Thus:

```
def likeByHashtag(self,hashtag):
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/' + hashtag)
```

Would archive what you're looking for.

Otherwise another solution using xPath would be:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//div[contains(., {hashtag})]')
```

Credits to [@kjhughes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27208749/14059235)