# Xpath Expression Interpretation

Tags: xpath

Can someone please explain what the below Xpath expressions mean?

1. `//node()[not(*)][not(normalize-space())]`
2. `//node()[not(*)][not(normalize-space())][not(boolean(@Key))]`
3. `//node()[not(text())]`

I understand `//node()` means any node, but not sure with the following expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//node()[not(*)][not(normalize-space())]
```

All element, text, comment, and processing-instruction nodes, anywhere in the document, that do not have a child element node and whose string value is either empty or consists entirely of whitespace

```
//node()[not(*)][not(normalize-space())][not(boolean(@Key))]
```

As above, with the extra condition that there is no @Key attribute. The last predicate is badly written: it could be shortened to `[not(@Key)]` without changing its meaning.

```
//node()[not(text())]
```

All element, text, comment, and processing-instruction nodes, anywhere in the document, that do not have a child text node.

Comment: OK far better and more exact.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated (thanks to @Michael Kay comment)**
First one:
`//node()` all nodes in the document (including text, comment and processing instruction but not attributes)
 `[not(*)]` which does not have any child **element nodes**
`[not(normalize-space())]` which does not have any text content (beside  of whitespace).

Second one:
Same as first one but additional:

`[not(boolean(@Key))]` the node has no attribute Key 
Update:
For the third one have a look to [e.g. this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9493870/2115381) 
In your example this will also ignore nodes with any text content (even white space)

Comment: and the third one please?

Comment: Not an entirely accurate answer. For example `//node()` does not select all nodes in the document - it doesn't select the document node, and it doesn't select attributes and namespaces; also `[not(*)]` allows child text nodes but not child element nodes..