# Retrive event logs contains specific string in DATA tag

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, event-log, event-viewer

I have developed a `MFC` application which reads `windows event logs` from `event log file` (`EVTX`) file and parse it to render in application

For reading log file, I am using `XPATH` query to retrieve specific event logs from `event log file` file consist of 40000 records

Sample log records look like below code

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Error_Log"/>
    <EventID Qualifiers="20225">6002</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-05-31T10:37:16.000000000Z"/>
    <EventRecordID>11679958</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Security/>
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>16:07:16.339:(A)[app.exe] [scan] m_id = [1254]</Data>
    <Binary>31363A30373A31362E3333393A2841295B7275706170702E6578655D205B5363616E5D206D5F6964203D205B313235345D</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Here I want to retrieve only those log records where `<DATA>` tag contains sub-string value `m_id`. To achieve this I tried below `query`

```
LPWSTR Query = _T("Event/EventData[Data(Data='m_id')]");

EVT_HANDLE Results = EvtQuery(NULL, Path, Query, EvtQueryFilePath | EvtQueryForwardDirection);
```

But I am not able to retrieve any logs even if string `m_id` is present in input log file as shown in above code

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with XPath 2 by using contains()

Full Events:

```
/Event[EventData/Data[contains(text(),'m_id')]]
/Event[EventData/Data[contains(string(),'m_id')]]
```

Data Only:

```
/Event/EventData/Data[contains(string(),'m_id')]
/Event/EventData/Data[contains(text(),'m_id')]
```

[Test Xpaths here](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)

[Advanced Xpath Filtering](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2011/09/26/advanced-xml-filtering-in-the-windows-event-viewer/)

[string vs text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493732/difference-between-text-and-string)

Comment: Hi @ffhighwind , I tried mentioned all 4 combinations . but no luck , Still below method returning nothing                                                                             EVT_HANDLE Results = EvtQuery(NULL, Path, Query, EvtQueryFilePath | EvtQueryForwardDirection);

Comment: It's possible it's related to system32 redirection and you may need to call wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection. It could also be a UAC issue. Try opening Path to see if it exists. Also you should try calling [GetLastError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387064/how-to-get-the-error-message-from-the-error-code-returned-by-getlasterror) if EvtQuery returned NULL.

Comment: By "opening" Path I mean calling fopen or fstream::open(Path).good() on it. Either way I would appreciate an upvote.