# xpath: find a node whose content has a provided string

Tags: xpath

I have some HTML like this:

```
   <div>  Make </div>
```

And I want to match it based on the fact that the content of the node contains the text "Make".

Put another way "Make" is a substring of the `div` node's content and I want to make such a match on this node using XPath.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the `<div>` tag cannot contain "Make"? If so, why? Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/6442430/299327

Comment: No - I mean the div tag must contain "Make"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious solution would be

```
//div[contains(., 'Make')]
```

but this will find all divs that contain the string "Make" anywhere within their content, so not only will it find the example you've given in the question but also any ancestor div of that one, or any divs where that substring is buried deep in a descendant element.

If you only want cases where that string is *directly* inside the div with no other intervening elements then you'd have to use the slightly more complex

```
//div[text()[contains(., 'Make')]]
```

This is subtly different from

```
//div[contains(text(), 'Make')]
```

which would look only in the *first* text node child of the div, so it would find `<div>Make<br/>Break</div>` but *not* `<div>Break<br/>Make</div>`

If you want to allow for intervening elements *other than* div, then try

```
//div[contains(., 'Make')][not(.//div[contains(., 'Make'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is what you are looking for: `//div[contains(text(),'Make')]`

If this will not work you can try: `//div[contains(.,'Make')]`. This will find all divs, which contain 'Make' in any attribute.

Answer (score 1):

To find that node anywhere in the document, you would need this:

```
//div[contains(text(), "Make")]
```